# Proof request: Trajectories in the stable manifold of a non-hyperbolic fixed point converge to the fixed point

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Let $\dot{x} = f(x)$ be a smooth dynamical system on a finite dimensional vector space $\mathbb{V}$. Suppose $f(0)=0$ is a non-hyperbolic fixed point. For simplicity, I set $Df(0)$ to have a simple $0$ eigenvalue, and all other eigenvalues have negative real part. From center manifold theory, I know there is a unique stable manifold and a possibly non-unique center manifold. Is it true that points starting in the stable manifold are guaranteed to asymptotically converge to $0$? If so, I would love to see a proof of this. I tried searching for one, but am having a difficult time. I would think the proof is similar to the stable manifold theorem, but for sanity's sake would prefer to see a proper proof.

Comment: How do you define the stable manifold?

Comment: @LutzLehmann It is defined here (https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Ordinary_Differential_Equations_(Wiggins)/10%3A_Center_Manifold_Theory/10.01%3A_Center_Manifold_Theory), albeit loosely.

Comment: The property of your claim is usually the definition of the stable manifold, see chapter 6 of your link, so there is nothing to prove. Thus the question about alternative characterizations.